# how can I sum every n cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, sum

In Excel I need to just add up some cells across a row, like this:

```
=sum(A1+D1+G1+J1)
```

As you can see, it's just every third cell. I have to do this often so I'd love an equation I could copy and paste.

Is there a way to say "sum every third cell from A1 to V1"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN(A1:V1),3)=1,A1:V1,0))
```

Confirm with Ctrl, Shift and Enter and curly brackets will surround the formula.

[image]

Btw, all this stuff is online.